# Tableview Dominates UI in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uitableview

I started my iPhone application as a navigation-based app which has served me well until now. In the nib for my TableViewController, I see the TableView (with its example values of California cities) but I'm able to drop any other UI elements on it (for example an UILabel).

I can add a UIWindow which gives me a separate window to add stuff onto but when I start my app all I see is the table view.

What am I missing? How do you mesh these elements together?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use UIViewController instead and put a UITableView on that. That way you can move things around at your discretion. You will have to manually implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource though.

Answer (score 0):

A UITableView is composed from cells (UITableViewCell objects).

Apple's own  [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1) should help out.  Plus, when you get to customizing and using cells this [section](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) will help.

Comment: I would agree with cirrostratus that in some cases you can use UIViewController + UITableView more effectively than UITableViewController. See this good post: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/recreating-uitableviewcontroller-to.html

If the use-case is pretty straight-forward I'd stick with UITableViewController.  If you're using core data also look out for the very useful NSFetchedResultsController.